# Bootstrap carousel data-interval to go false on click of a component

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have added a bootstrap carousel to my site and I have one video and 2 images in the slides. Clients requirement is to auto slide the carousel for 3000ms and stop sliding when  you click play button the video. I tried this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#carouselMarsIndicators").click(function(){
    $('.carousel[data-ride="carousel"]').attr('data-interval', 'false');
    });
 });
```

But couldn't able to achieve it. This issue can be adjustable for desktop screens if you mousover but for mobiles and tablets you need to have click function.

Comment: use .carousel('pause') to pause the sliding when user click the play button.

Comment: I tried that too but it didn't seem to be working. Do we have any good solution other than this

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('.carousel').carousel({interval:false});
```